# JSON Object to properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to store the results from JSON in properties, but I don't know how. I'm using ASP.NET with MVC 4/Razor.

My model's constructor is:

```
    public UserModel()
    {
        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        string response = request.DownloadString(url);

        JObject _naturalUserObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
    }
```

And I have the follow properties:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int Avatar { get; set; }
```

To access a simple value from my JSON:

```
_naturalUserObject["users"][0]["name"];
```

The final question is: how can I store each value from my JObject in my model's properties and finally display it into my view?

Thanks in advance.

**/EDIT/**
My model now is:

```
    public UserModel()
    {
        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        string response = request.DownloadString(String.Format("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key={0}&steamids={1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SteamApiKey"].ToString(), HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SteamIdCookie"].Value));

        string _naturalUserObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response);
    }
```

And one of my property is:

```
    private string _avatar;
    public string Avatar
    {
        get { return _avatar; }
        set { _avatar = _naturalUserObject["response"]["players"][0]["avatar"]; }
    }
```

But without success. =(

Comment: `YourObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(response);`

Comment: @I4V "YourObject" can be a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say you have the following Json

```
string yourJsonString = "{\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Foo\",\"LAST_NAME\":\"Bar\"}";
```

You could model this Json as:

```
public class JsonModel
{
    [JsonProperty("FIRST_NAME")]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("LAST_NAME")]
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Note that you can use `JsonPropertyAttribute` to tell `Json.Net` what the property's corresponding json field is.

Now, that you have your model set up, can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(...)` to get a strongly typed instance of your json model.

```
JsonModel jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(yourJsonString);
string firstName = jsonModel.FirstName; // Foo
string lastName = jsonModel.LastName; // Bar
```

As someone had mentioned, if you do it this way, you won't have to deal with `JObject` and moreover, it will force you to actually understand the structure of the json being returned.

Specifically in your example, you could store an object of type `JsonModel` and in your model's constructor initialize it using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`. Your public properties could then just call into that `JsonModel` instance and get the appropriate values.

Here's a more detailed example. Assume you are getting back the json I had provided above and are using the same model we created before. Let's say you have a private field in your class of type `JsonModel`

```
private JsonModel jsonModel;
```

You can initialize it in your constructor:

```
public UserModel()
{
    WebClient request = new WebClient();
    string response = request.DownloadString(url);
    jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(response);
}
```

Now, your public properties can simply call into this `JsonModel` object.

```
public string FirstName
{
    get { return jsonModel.FirstName; }
    set { jsonModel.FirstName = value; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, dude! Was close I think. But, I place my jsonModel and these properties into my UserModel's constructor?

Comment: Well, that's just one way of doing it. `jsonModel` is really just an object which represents the json. You can have `UserModel` act as a wrapper around it or even just use `UserModel` to model the json. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hmmm! Wow, more clearly now, but I have one question — when I execute the UserModel through his controller, he returns a StackOverflow Exception, and this occurs because I have some trouble on my constructor — Do you think of why? To be more specific, the VS' debugger accuses the "response" string variable. And, how can I create the JsonModel type/class?

Comment: Hmm well you'll have to post the code for where you're using this controller and what the exact exception is.

Comment: Controller calls the model using this implementation: 
`public ActionResult Test()
{
            var model = new UserModel();

            return Content(model.DisplayName);
        }`

The exception is "stackoverflow exception"

Comment: A stackoverflow exception occurs because of unbounded recursion. If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say soemthign bad is happening in `Content(...)`

Comment: Actually the problem is here: `var model = new UserModel();`. If I remove it, works like a magic!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Json.net you can deserialize directly into a clr object (which could be your viewmodel or model), you won't have to deal with JObject.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myviewmodelormodel>(myjsondata);
```

Comment: Can you show me a practice example? I didn't understand all of your explanation — starting with "clr object".

Comment: Oh, thank you about the edit. But, how can I store this in my property?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `ServiceStack.Text` (available as a standalone NuGet package install, without the rest of the framework if you don't need it).

This adds two nice extension methods:

```
public class MyPOCO
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public int Age {get; set; }
}
```

And later:

```
string json = myPocoInstance.ToJson();
```

and:

```
MyPOCO instance = jsonString.FromJson<MyPOCO>();
```

Very fast too!

Comment: Sorry, but how can I apply this in my case?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the object back as a string in JSON format. You can use the JSON de-serializer like this:

Put this into a static class this will become an extension method to all strings

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this string json)
{
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
                obj = (T) serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            }
            return obj;
}
```

**EX:**

- this calls a url getting the result set in a string, then calls the
  extension method to return an object.
- the url returns  MyPOCO

> ```
> var stringValue = HttpGet(url);//how you get the value from a web service call
> var myUserModel = stringValue.Deserialize<MyPOCO>();
> ```

Comment: Thanks, dude! By the way, I think your answer is more complex that what I want to make. I can't see how I can apply this in my case — can you understand?

Comment: "MyPOCO" object what you referred is the same that was answered before in this thread? If yes, still not clearly for me. By the way, thanks!

Comment: your controller is the one calling the web service. Its then setting the properties on the model.

Comment: Actually not. I've calling my web service on Model, at the constructor.

Comment: I'm saying you should have your controller call the webservice. To keep separation of concerns from the model to the controller. the Model's focus is to binding to your view. The controller gets the data.

Comment: Oh, I got it. So what you said was referring to the model, not the controller, right? If yes, I have to move my UserModel's constructor to a method inside controller, right?

Comment: Yes, you controllers act as a 'traffic cop' populating the user model, and models tend to be POCOs (empty get;set;).